# Offset at bottom of vuejs + vuetify application only on mobile

Tags: css, vue.js, github, vuetify.js

How come there is an offset at the bottom of my website and it is only visible on my phone (Xiami note 7) and (icognito) Chrome mobile browser?

[image: https://photos.app.goo.gl/igaYU2gsBb99aMLT7]

https://pandaquests.github.io/test2/

Code
https://github.com/pandaquests/test2/tree/gh-pages?files=1

At first I thought it had something to do with the size of the content container. But I already set it to `height: 100vh;`. And it works fine on Laptop/Desktop browsers also in the inspect tool for mobile view it looks fine. However, on a real smartphone it looks off, i.e. there is an offset of visible height (see image).

It's hosted on github-pages written with vueJS, vuetify

I only used standard vuetify components with minor tweaks:

**App bar:**

https://codepen.io/thadeuszlay/pen/MWgZQzr?&editable=true&editors=101

**Cards:**

https://codepen.io/thadeuszlay/pen/wvwRyQz?&editable=true&editors=101

Comment: Can you share all of you application code? The error is not in these two components

Comment: @MarcRo see update

Comment: You have accidentally shared minified code.:)

Comment: @MarcRo please go to master branch in src folder

Comment: You gave your `v-sheet` component a max-height of `600px`. I didn't test it but assume that's the mistake

Comment: @MarcRo you are correct! I thought I fixed it but now I remember I `reset --hard` before and that reverted that fix probably. Thanks. If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it as best answer. (still strange that it looks good on desktop/laptop and also the dev tool in the mobile view....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your github repo shows a style-attribute with `max-height="600px"` on a wrapping `v-sheet` component that somehow snuck in there :)